# Drupal Multisite, same module name, different site

Tags: 7, multi-sites

We have a module that needs to be the same name, but its functionality will change for each site.

Is it an ok practice to put put them in sites/site1/modules/MODULE_NAME and sites/site2/modules/MODULE_NAME

Will this cause any problems with drupal if they have the same name, but are in different sites?

Comment: Thank you, if you want to get points please post this as answer

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are in the individual sites' directories, the are only visible to the sites they are associated with. Should be no problem.